# Django / Cactus and truncate words with markdown

Tags: django

Trying to use {{ post|truncatewords:"100" }} for a teaser in Cactus.  The post is using the markdown filter and truncate words is showing the html.  I also tried {{ post|truncatewords:"100"|markdown }} which does seem like it is attempting to format correctly, however line breaks and body tags still show.

Example Output:

{'body': u'\n\n

Cactus templates are set up using the Django Template Language. Django\u2019s template language is both powerful and easy to use. A template is simply a HTML file. Let\'s take a look at how to use the blog template.

\n\n
General file str...

Seems like this should be pretty straight forward but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `post` is a dictionary, and the post body you want to show is under the `body` key. You probably want something like:

```
{{ post.body|markdown|truncatewords_html:100 }}
```